# How to place --header-html above margin-top with WKHTMLTOPDF

Tags: html, pdf, file-conversion

I have a (in my opinion) common scenario where I want to print a header with a logo on every page. The text on the document can overflow and needs to start on the second page below the header. The logo should start at 10 mm from the top. The text on the second page should start at 40mm from the top of the second page. If I specify top-marin -T 40mm then the header starts at 40mm also. If I specify -T 10mm then the text starts at 10mm also. I have tried to position the header with a CSS style attribute at "position:absolute;top:10mm" from the top and -T 40mm, and I have also tried to position using "margin-top:-30mm" but none of these work. Printing outside the specified margin parameters seems to be impossible. Am I missing something?
The --footer-html is placed under the specified bottom-marign -B, why is the header not placed above the top margin?

Comment: Please edit your post to show what have you tried

Comment: Hi Jon, all html is generated on the server and is quite complex. I'll try to extract the different parts in an easy setup and test this manually. I'll post the results. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the problem. First of all the header-html file needs a !doctype html, just like the body part. Next, after adding a position:absolute;bottom:10mm; style attribute to the header, it appeared beautifully.